# Get Error 'invalid character range' from regexp in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have this code,

```
SELECT id
FROM animals
WHERE NOT HEX(description) REGEXP '^([0-7][10-191A-1F])*$'
LIMIT 1
```

but when i run it, I get invalid character range from regexp.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What character range are you trying to cover with that second part, `[10-191A-1F]`?

Comment: Yup. Is my script correct?

Comment: Sorry, maybe I wasn't clear. What are you trying to accomplish with that second group, `[10-191A-1F]`? That doesn't look like a valid character range, though my mySQL regexps are pretty rusty.